# Marshalling part of a struct

Tags: c#, arrays, struct, marshalling

I've been trying to figure out whether it is possible to marshal a part of a struct into an array of bytes without any errors. The reason for this is because the part not going to be marshalled has a variable sized array. This is the the code I'm using.

C#:

```cs
public struct Random { 
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    public int a;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    public int b;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray, SafeArraySubType = VarEnum.VT_RECORD)]
    public Random1[] r;
}

public struct Random1 { 
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    public int c;
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    int size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Random));
    int s = 4;
    Random r = new Random();
    Random r1 = new Random();

    r.a = 1;
    r.b = 5;
    r.r = new Random1[2];
    r.r[0].c = 10;
    r.r[1].c = 12;

    IntPtr p = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
    try {
        byte[] arr = new byte[size];
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(r, p, false);
        Marshal.Copy(p, arr, 0, 8);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(p);
        p = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
        Marshal.Copy(arr, 0, p, 8);
        r1 = (Random) Marshal.PtrToStructure(p, typeof(Random));
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(p);
        p = IntPtr.Zero;
        Debug.WriteLine(r1.a);
        Debug.WriteLine(r1.b);
        Debug.WriteLine(r1.r[0].c);
        Debug.WriteLine(r1.r[1].c);
    } finally {
        if (p != IntPtr.Zero) {
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(p);
        }
    }
}
```

When I try this code it gives me an ArgumentException in the StructureToPtr. What am I doing wrong or can this be done? If not I've read something about using IntPtr. Could someone tell me how to do this?

Comment: What does the ArgumentException say?

Comment: This is the Message **The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))**

Comment: The problem here is the `SafeArray`, the interop doesn't quite know how to handle it.

Comment: It was solved it by using fixed size arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I've been thinking long and hard about this one, and after trying several (*very* hackish) options, I have arrived at the conclusion that what you are doing is not possible.

First of all, it isn't possible to directly marshal an array of variable length, because no meaningful size offset can be computed by the Marshal, and therefore the memory layout can not be determined.

If the struct wouldn't contain any non-blittable, non-primitive types, you could theoretically  do something like this:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[8];
Marshal.Copy(new IntPtr(&r), buffer, 0, 8);

IntegersOnlyStruct partialStruct;
fixed (byte* b = buffer)
    partialStruct = *(IntegersOnlyStruct*) b;
```

And obtain the two integers contained in the struct that way. However, since your `Random1` is a non-primitive, non-blittable type this approach won't get you very far either.

The `IntPtr` approach to keep a pointer to a memory location where your `Random1` struct is kept in memory is an alternative that could possibly work, but I haven't gone in-depth on that, yet.

I think you may want to re-think the way you approach this, as it's not possible in its current form. If anybody can prove otherwise, I'd be happy to see how it can be done.

Comment: Thanks. I've solved it by using fixed size arrays. But as you said I would like to know if it is possible